# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Hello I´m webscraping a bookmaker to get the names of teams which are playing as next (I wanna scrape the names of germany bundesliga). I wanna save the strings of the names in a csv file but im getting an error. The content of the .csv file when I open it is:

70,111,114,116,117,110,97,32,68,195,188,115,115,101,108,100,111,114,102

it´s the ascii code for "Fortuna Düsseldorf"

I´ve tried it wihtout encode("utf-8") in line 27 and several other things but still getting the error. Line 18 isn´t the problem since the program wrote the first name of the team in the .csv file. I won´t paste the second loop for the second teamnames since it´s the same code but for the second teams in the html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import os
import csv

class NamenCollector:


    def NamenHolen(self, url, pfad):
        bool1 = False
        bool2 = False
        self.page = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, 'lxml')
        Namen1 = self.soup.find_all('div', class_='live_group1')
        Namen2 = self.soup.find_all('div', class_='live_group2')
        if os.stat(pfad).st_size == 0:
            nam = self.soup.find('div', class_='live_group1').string.strip().encode("utf-8")
            with open(pfad, 'a') as csvFile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                writer.writerow(nam)
                csvFile.close()

        if os.stat(pfad).st_size != 0:
            a1 = pandas.read_csv(pfad)
            for name1 in Namen2:
                nam1 = name1.find('div', class_='live_group1').string.strip().encode("utf-8")
                for name1_1 in a1:
                    if nam1 == name1_1:
                        bool1 = True
                if bool1 == False:
                    with open(pfad, 'a') as csvFile:
                        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
                        writer.writerow(nam1)
                        csvFile.close()
                        bool1 = False
bun_url = 
'https://www.cashpoint.de/de/bets/bets.html?group=683883sportid=1&filter='

bun_pfad = 'C:\Man\Deutschland\Bundesliga.csv'

d_Bundesliga = NamenCollector()

d_Bundesliga.NamenHolen(bun_url, bun_pfad)
```

The error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: server may send data in different encoding - ie. `latin1` (`iso-8859-1`), `latin2` (`iso8859-2`), `cp1250`, `cp1252`, etc. so first you would have to check on Internet what encoding uses char with code `0xfc`

Comment: code `print( b'\xfc'.decode('latin1') )` shows `ü`. Other encodings also shows `ü` but `utf-8` shows error message. So page can use any of these encodings to send data.

Comment: so as google says it´s 0xFC is the hexa code for ü in german. It´s an austrian bookmaker. Austrian is german language why should they use latin strings? So i used .encode("utf-8") in line 27. And the head of the html shows <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: `Latin` means roman languages like German and many other Western European languages. `Latin2` was for East/Central European languages. Both where very popular on web pages not so long time ago. Maybe there is `<meta charset="utf-8">` but sometime people use data from files which are not encoded in `utf-8`

Comment: furas what do you wanna suggest me  to do?

Comment: you didn't show full error message (starting at word "Traceback") but it shows which line of code makes problem. If problem is in `.encode("utf-8")` then I would use `.encode("latin1")` . If problem is with `BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, ...)` then I would try `BeautifulSoup(self.page.content.decode('latin1'), ...)`

Comment: sadly i can´t post whole error message since it´s too long

Comment: `writer.writerow(nam)` should be `writer.writerow([nam])`. This is because `csv.writerow` accepts an iterable and turns each element in the iterable into a column.  Since the string "Fortuna Düsseldorf", is an iterable, you a csv where each letter in the name is in a separate column.  By passing `csv.writer` a list with a single element you will get a csv with a single column.  Same applies to `writer.writerow(nam1)`.  This may not solve the encoding problem, but at least you should get a better csv.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.7.4

Comment: at least find in error message lines which shows which line of code in your script makes problem.

Comment: I replaced writer.writerow(nam) with writer.writerow([nam]) as snakecharmerb said. So i guess it helped but something is wrong with this error in line 27: nam1 = name1.find('div', class_='live_group1').string.strip().encode("utf-8") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'. It seems i iterate wrong over Namen2 in the for loop?